# PHP Syntax error unexpected "," with $_POST

Tags: php, post, syntax-error

I'm a PHP beginner and I have a problem: when I use this:

```
if(isset($_POST['doc_lang'], $_POST['doc_title'], $_POST['doc_header'], $_POST['doc_body'], $_POST['doc_footer']) AND !empty($_POST['doc_lang'], $_POST['doc_title'], $_POST['doc_header'], $_POST['doc_body'], $_POST['doc_footer']))
```

I have this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in (...)/WebDoc.php on line 3.

What is the correct syntax? Thank

Comment: `empty()` only takes 1 parameter

Comment: Please always describe what you have, what happens and what you expect to happen instead. Otherwise no one can help you

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) so depending what you are trying to do, it could for example be `||` or `&&`

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, `empty()` cannot accept multiple variables the way that `isset()` does.